# Get the position of a bit and if it is set

Tags: java, bit

I have a function which checks, whether a bit in an int is set or not.
But I think there will be a much faster implementation, since this one is linear and can't be the most efficient one, although I know the int should be between 1 and 1024.

```
 public static int getBitPos(final int n) {
        if (Integer.bitCount(n) != 1)
            return Constants.UNDEFINED;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; ++i) {
                if (testBit(n, i))
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return Constants.UNDEFINED;
    }
```

Where `testBit` is the following standard function:

```
public static boolean testBit(final int n, final int pos) {
    int mask = 1 << pos;
    return (n & mask) == mask;
}
```

But there mast be a faster way, isn't there? If I have the value 17 and I want to know if the 4th bit (n = 8) is set? There should be a faster way to check whether the bit for n=8 is set...

Hope you can help me...

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks for the support. The comments and answers brought me to my mistake. I was setting the values wrongly, which made it more complicated than needed. I was never good at bit shifting.
I set the value like this, if I wanted the second bit to be set:

```
value = 2;
```

If I wanted the 4th bit to be set too, I added the value according to the 4th bit:

```
value += 8;
```

So value was 10, and the 2nd and 4th bit were set. So I saved the numbers in my class, instead of the bit-positions (8 as value, instead of 4 for the 4th bit, ...).
After changing this, I could get rid of my unnecessary function, which was way over the top! 
Thanks for all help!

Comment: Have a look at [Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#numberOfTrailingZeros(int))

Comment: Why iterate all the way though `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when all you have are a maximum of 64 bits?

Comment: Here's the question to seem to be trying to answer: _"If I have the value `n` and I want to know if the `m`th bit is set"_ Why aren't you passing 2 `int` parameters to the function? Or, are you just trying to figure out if _any_ bit is set? Either way, you can get an answer in constant time.

Comment: Yeah... you are right, which brought me to the other problem, that I was setting the bits by numbers, but I will explain it above. You showed me my mistake in thinking! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code always returns the lowest bit that is 1, if there is only one. You can achieve the same by doing this:

```
int foo = whatever;
int lowestSetBit = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(foo) + 1;
```

Your code would be

```
public static int getBitPos(final int n) {
    if (Integer.bitCount(n) == 1)
        return Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(n) + 1;
    return Constants.UNDEFINED;
}
```

Comment: Ok... you just reminded me of something. Unfortunately you were right, I had a mistake in thinking.
I changed the whole thing. Thanks!